# border-radius and RTL issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, right-to-left

I noticed when I use border-radius with padding and the direction of HTML is RTL it is not working as expected. It works fine if remove the direction part `dir="rtl"`. The following codes will show how it works without and with `dir="rtl"`

without `dir="rtl"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        .main {
            padding:5px;
        }
        .tag{
                  background-color: #0473c0;
                  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
                  padding:5px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="main">
            <span class="tag">test</span>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image: no problem here]

with  `dir="rtl"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        .main {
            padding:5px;
        }
        .tag{
                  background-color: #0473c0;
                  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
                  padding:5px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="main">
            <span class="tag">test</span>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:[image]

As you can see the text moved to the left and background moved to the right. I tested it on IE10 and IE9. Is there any fix for this problem or any work around?

Comment: I can reproduce it. Weird issue. It seems making the span an `inline-block` helps, though I'm not sure what it does to the flow of the text in RTL documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the `.tag` display as an `inline-block` seems to resolve this:

```
  .tag {
    background-color: #0473c0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding:5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

See also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PHVp/) for a working demo. (Tested in IE10, Win8).

However, I'm not sure whether this messes with the flow of text in RTL documents in any way.